# Forward all email to another user in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, forwarding

I am trying to forward emails for a user who has left our organisation to another user, but I cannot find how to do it.

We have recently upgraded to Exchange 2010 (from 2003), which now runs on a seperate server to our Active Directory. Because of this, there is no 'Exchange General' tab in a users properties, under AD Users and Computers.

I cannot find a way to do this through Exchange Management Console either, so I wonder if someone could please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In EMC go to Recipient Configuration>Mailbox, find the mailbox for the departed user, right click and select properties, go to the Mail Flow Settings tab, select Delivery Options and click the Properties button. From there you can set the forwarding options.

Comment: Perfect description, thank you - was looking for ages!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

Find the user in exchange management console under recipients -> mailboxes

Right click, properties

Go to the mail flow settings tab

Select forward to and enter the person to forward to.