# User left company, exchange 2010 mailbox questions

Tags: exchange-2010, mailbox

A user has left the company and I have several questions related to the mailbox in Exchange 2010.

At first we just left the mailbox and monitored it ourselves.

Now we've forward all emails to another account (followed this: [Forward all email to another user in Exchange 2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/490773/forward-all-email-to-another-user-in-exchange-2010) )

Now I'm looking for the best strategy, we would like to keep the mails (as we sometimes need to look in older emails for some projects that user worked on) but from an administrator perspective I don't want to keep the mailbox in exchange 2010 (it also takes up a license).

What would be the best to do? can you transfer a mailbox to another user subfolder? can emails be exported to files (?)

your advice or experiences would be useful.

Comment: Can you convert it to a shared mailbox?

Comment: @Tim, i have no experience with this. What would be the reason you want to convert this to a shared mailbox?

Comment: Shared mailboxes don't use licenses and you can allow users that need to search the email access to the shared mailbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we do is:
Change the password for the user account (if you simply disable, the mailbox can be accessed up to 15 mins after due to synchronization time).
Move the mailaddress to a "Noreply" address with an out of office message stating that the person they have mailed is no longer employed with the company
Export to pst from Exchange shell.

```
New-MailboxExportRequest [MAILBOXALIAS] -baditemlimit 500 -acceptlargedataloss -FilePath C:\PATH\FILENAME.pst
```

The -baditemlimit is set to accept X amount of corrupted items
The -acceptlargedataloss is set because the value of baditemlimit is above 100
The -FilePath can also be set to a networkpath

Disabled user account.
Delete mailbox.

Comment: This is a good answer, just keep in mind that for a brief period after moving the address to a new mailbox, internal users emailing that address may get a bounceback, as the cached recipient in Outlook will be using the X400/X500 address, which you might want to add to the NoReply mailbox as well.

Comment: @DylanKnoll Very good point :) - I'll add it to our procedure.